# iOS: Sorting and grouping NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have two tables with the following structure

MainCategory:

```
name position hasSubCategories
```

SubCategory:

```
name position display belongsToMainCategory
```

Now I want to display all subcategories (where display attribute = YES) grouped by main category. The main category sections should be sorted as defined by position and the subcategories itself (within the section) by their position attribute. (name by the way can be the same for a certain main category...my tables have more attributes but they aren't relevant to understand the problem).
But my order is completely messed up. Why? Here's my code for the FetchedResultsController:

```
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"SubCategory"];

    NSSortDescriptor *mainCatPosition = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                            initWithKey:@"belongsToMainCategory.position" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *subCatPosition = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                            initWithKey:@"position" ascending:YES];

    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:mainCatPosition,subCatPosition,nil];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"display = %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    [self.db.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                       managedObjectContext:self.budgetDatabase.managedObjectContext
                                                                         sectionNameKeyPath:@"belongsToMainCategory.name"
                                                                                  cacheName:nil];
```

Comment: Can show show a (small) example of what you get and what you expect?

Comment: At the moment sections are mixed up. The sections are alphabetically ordered (which is wrong, they should be ordered according to belongsToMainCategory.position) and the number of rows within the section are also according to alphabetical order which is wrong too. However the sub categories are correctly ordered according to position. So the whole main category part is ordered wrong, and especially due to the wrong number of rows within each section all subcategories are wrong distributed to the main categories.

Comment: The sectionNameKeyPath must be "compatible" with the first sort descriptor. Does `sectionNameKeyPath:@"belongsToMainCategory.position"` give the expected result? Can there be multiple categories with different names, but the same position?

Comment: Yes! That belongsToMainCategory.position works! Thanks alot!! But why? Is this sectionNameKeyPath sorted in some way as well?

Comment: I'll write it as an answer ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key path used as `sectionNameKeyPath:` argument to the fetched results controller must
be the same key that is used in the first sort descriptor *or* generate the same relative ordering.

The fetched results controller first orders all fetched objects according to the first
sort descriptor and then groups the objects into sections according to the `sectionNameKeyPath`. Therefore using different key paths (as in your case "belongsToMainCategory.position" vs. "belongsToMainCategory.name") does not work.
This could even cause a runtime error about "out of order sections".