# NSortDescriptors, table rows not sorting

Tags: ios, nssortdescriptor

I have a tableview that has section headers and section rows.
Im trying to sort the headers and rows with different key paths. I want the headers to be sort by date, and the rows to be sorted by a different key path.

```
-(NSFetchRequest *)entryListFetchRequest{
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"NapEntry"];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO],
                                   [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"timePicker" ascending:NO selector:@selector(compare:)]]];

return fetchRequest;
}
```

The headers are sorting properly, but the rows are not. The rows are an NSDate being sorted by time. Right now they are just sorting by order of input, not by time.

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController{
if(_fetchedResultsController != nil){
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

CoreDataStack *coreDataStack =[CoreDataStack defaultStack];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [self entryListFetchRequest];

_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionName" cacheName:nil];
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

here is my cellForRow method:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
NapCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

NapEntry *entry = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell configureCellForEntry:entry];

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


return cell;
}
```

Any thoughts into why the second sortDescriptorWithKey "timePicker", is not sorting the table rows?

***ADDED NSManagedObject subclass for entity****

```
#import "NapEntry.h"


@implementation NapEntry

@dynamic date;
@dynamic timePicker;
@dynamic timer;


//assigns section headers
- (NSString *)sectionName {
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:self.date];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE  MMM d, yyyy"];

return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
}
@end
```

Comment: The key used as `sectionNameKeyPath` must also be used in the first sort descriptor, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812564/ios-sorting-and-grouping-nsfetchedresultscontroller.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for the response, ill try and explain whats going on best I can. Im using a method called sectionName to set my sectionName key path. (see the above added code).This is doing a great job of setting my header information. Because there is this method, I do not have an 'sectionName' attribute in my data model. Therefore, when i use 'sectionName' as my sectionNameKeyPath as well as my first sort descriptor, I get an error that says 'sectionName' isn't included in my entity (because it isn't). Anyway to get around this? I still need to sort my sections and my rows differently.

Comment: But the sectionNameKeyPath and the first sort descriptor must generate the same relative ordering.

Comment: correct, thats why I was using the 'date' sortDescriptorWithKey, because it seemed to satisfy the relative ordering. Its the second sortDescriptor that doesn't seem to be sorting

Comment: Your `sectionName` does not preserve the relative ordering of the "date" attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NSFetchedResultsController` object sectionNameKeyPath property value must correspond to the `NSFetchRequest` first sort descriptor, that's how you specify section headers.  The remaining sort descriptors are used to sort rows within each section.

So basically you should be able to just try this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sd1 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"sectionName" ascending:NO];
NSSortDescriptor *sd2 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
NSSortDescriptor *sd3 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"datePicker" ascending:NO];  // note sure compare: is needed
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sd1, sd2, sd3];
```

This is assuming your model object has a sectionName attribute which you are sorting sections by.

Comment: It looks like your 1st sort descriptor is by date, 2nd is by datePicker.  Then use tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: to format the date that goes in your section headers.

Comment: feel free to accept this answer if it was useful to you ;)